# Installing elinks on OSX

Tags: software-installation, osx

I am trying to download the text based browser elinks by following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A2gzn8QAlWA but I could not because the terminal gave me the error "sudo: apt-get: command not found". what should I do to fix this so that I can download elinks? I use
Mac OS X version 10.11.5.

Here is my console after trying to install using brew:

```
Last login: Thu Jul  7 12:32:57 on ttys000
➜  ~ sudo apt-get install  elinks
Password:
sudo: apt-get: command not found
➜  ~ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
It appears Homebrew is already installed. If your intent is to reinstall you
should do the following before running this installer again:
    ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
The current contents of /usr/local are bin Cellar CODEOFCONDUCT.md CONTRIBUTING.md etc Frameworks include lib Library LICENSE.txt opt README.md share SUPPORTERS.md .git .gitignore
➜  ~ brew install elinks
==> Downloading http://elinks.or.cz/download/elinks-0.11.7.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/elinks-0.11.7.tar.bz2
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/elinks/0.11.7_2 --without-spidermonkey --enable-256-colors
^C
➜  ~ elnks
zsh: command not found: elnks
➜  ~ elinks
zsh: command not found: elinks
➜  ~ /usr/local/Cellar/elinks
zsh: no such file or directory: /usr/local/Cellar/elinks
➜  ~ brew doctor
```

this is brew doctor:

```
Warning: The /usr/local is not writable.

You should probably change the ownership and permissions of /usr/local
back to your user account.
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local

Warning: The /usr/local directory is not writable.
Even if this directory was writable when you installed Homebrew, other
software may change permissions on this directory. For example, upgrading
to OS X El Capitan has been known to do this. Some versions of the
"InstantOn" component of Airfoil or running Cocktail cleanup/optimizations
are known to do this as well.

You should probably change the ownership and permissions of /usr/local
back to your user account.
  sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local

Warning: Python is installed at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework

Homebrew only supports building against the System-provided Python or a
brewed Python. In particular, Pythons installed to /Library can         interfere
with other software installs.

Warning: You have MacPorts or Fink installed:
  /opt/local/bin/port

This can cause trouble. You don't have to uninstall them, but you may want to
temporarily move them out of the way, e.g.

  sudo mv /opt/local ~/macports
```

and this is brew info elinks:

```
elinks: stable 0.11.7, devel 0.12pre6, HEAD
Text mode web browser
http://elinks.or.cz/
Not installed
From:         https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/elinks.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: openssl ✔
```

sudo brew install elinks

```
sudo brew install elinks
Password:
Error: Cowardly refusing to 'sudo brew install'
You can use brew with sudo, but only if the brew executable is owned by root.
However, this is both not recommended and completely unsupported so do so at
your own risk.
```

Answer (score 3):

`apt-get` is part of the Debian (or Ubuntu, etc), package `apt`.  Either you're not using one of those systems, or you haven't that package.

OSX has an `apt` package ([with MacPorts](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/sysutils/apt/Portfile)).  It is not something that you are likely to have installed on your computer.

You could install `elinks` with [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=elinks) or [homebrew](http://brewformulas.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search[term]=elinks&commit=Search).  But you will need a different tutorial.  (In any case, homebrew does not provide a formula for *apt*).